# Trying to logout particular user from Admin System: Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am writing the following code to logout particular user from Admin System.

I have session table. [**I am following this link**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session

```
$User = $this->Get($obj);
$UserSession = SessionModel::where('user_id', $obj->UserID)->first();
if($UserSession != null) {
    $UserSession->user_id = null;
    $UserSession->payload = null;
    $UserSession->save();
}
```

Is it a correct approach to do so?

Comment: Can't use `Auth::logout()` ? It basically do the same thing

Comment: I am trying to logout another user from an Admin System.

Comment: Why there should be a `SessionModel`? What is wrong with `session()` helper function?

Comment: @revo: Could you please explain your comment in an answer? Best Regards

Comment: Yet I'm not sure why you should create a model for unsetting a database driven session.

Comment: @Helper, As you are using Session table, i think you should delete the database entry for the particular user from the session table. That might work.

Answer (score 6):

You can really clean this up in one line of code:

```
$deleted = SessionModel::whereUserId($obj->UserID)->delete();

// Returns the number of deleted sessions.
return $deleted;
```

Deleting all session records that belong to a user will log the user out of all sessions they have.

For example, if a user is logged in on your application on their phone and computer, they will be logged out on both devices.

Comment: User will login again next time. Why should I increase the Auto Increment value unnecessarily?

Comment: Wouldn't really worry about the auto incrementing value in MySQL. You can always remove the primary auto-incrementing ID, but to be honest, are you really going to have more than 18446744073709551615 (eighteen quintillion) sessions in your db table? If you don't remove the record and just set the values to `null`, then you're just wasting a session row either way because a new row will automatically be created  on a new session.

Answer (score 3):

```
$User = $this->Get($obj);
$UserSession = SessionModel::where('user_id', $obj->UserID)->first();
if($UserSession != null) {
    $UserSession->user_id = null;
    $UserSession->payload = null;
    $UserSession->save();
}
```

You must noticed that is user can have more session records if user logs in with many different browser 
=> Solution: get all rows with given user_id in sessions table and delete them. Use useful Collection method

```
    $User = $this->Get($obj);
    // Get Collection Object
    $UserSessions = SessionModel::where('user_id', $obj->UserID)->get();
    if($UserSession != null) {
        // Use each method on Collection Object
        $UserSessions->each(function($UserSession){
              $UserSession->delete();      
        });
    }
```

Comment: User will login again next time. Why should I increase the Auto Increment value unnecessarily?

Comment: Another point is: I did not allow to have multiple sessions for a user.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider that the *user_id* in your **Session** table should be **nullable** and have a **default null** value, since users that are not logged in have no user id. Then your migration might have this line.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
```

Then deleting the row of a specific user in this table would delete that users session.